# How to prove that if $f=u+iv $ and for any $ z$, $u>0 $ or $v>0$, then $ f $ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $ f $ is entire such that $f=u+iv $ and for any $ z $, at least one of $u(z),v(z) $ is positive.

Prove that $ f $ constant.

Well, I've been thinking about it for a while and all I could say is that $ f $ maps all of the plane into the union of $Re(z)>0 $ and $Im(z)>0 $ and its image is an open set if $ f $ is not constant (by the open mapping theorem).

It feels like this should be a contradiction, but cant tell explicitly why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This follows immediately from the [Little Picard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: ^Little Picard is one way (my first thought as well), another way is to find a biholomorphism $\psi$ from the 3 quarters of the plane to say the unit disk. Then, Louiville's theorem will be helpful.

Comment: Im not familier with the tools of the proof as described in wikipedia. If anyone can reach a contradiction in another way, I would be greatful. I thought about using $\log(f(z)) $ which should be entire - can it lead somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need Little Picard. The well-known theorems characterizing the types of singularities are enough.

If $f$ is entire, then it is either a polynomial or transcendental (meaning that its power series expansion is infinite). If it is transcendental, then the map $g(z):=f\left(\frac 1z\right)$ has an essential singularity at $0$, so its image is dense in $\mathbb C$. And since the image of $g$ is either equal to that of $f$ or has only a single element missing ($f(0)$), the image of $f$ is also dense in $\mathbb C$. A contradiction to the given constraint, which says that a whole quarter plane is missing from the image. So $f$ must be a polynomial. But if it is a polynomial, it must be constant, since all non-constant polynomials are surjective according to the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: "Since the image of $g $ is either equal to that of $f$ or has only a single element missing" Why is it true?

Comment: Because $f(z)=g\left(\frac1z\right)$, and unless $z=0$, $\frac1z$ is in the domain of $g$.

Comment: So basically its a proof that the image of any entire function (which is not constant) is densed in $\mathbb{C} $. Wonderful

Comment: Exactly. Which is essentially a weaker version of Little Picard, but which can be proved more easily.

Answer (score 3):

The entire function $f$ omits an open set from its values, e.g. the disk about $z_0 = -1-i$ with radius 1. Now find a 1-1 mapping $g$ from the outside of this disk to the open unit disk and consider the entire bounded function $g \circ f$. Take it from there.

Look up any proof of the Little Picard Theorem (see @TonyK's comment). It uses the same idea.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Is there a way to get to a contradiction using $ \log\left(f\left(z\right)\right) $ which also should be entire?

Comment: Yes. $g(z) = \log f(z)$ is entire and has values in the strip $-\pi/2 < \Im w < \pi$. Therefore $\Im g$ is a bounded harmonic function, defined on the entire complex plane, and therefore constant. Then $g$ and hence $f$ are constant.